# d3 tree - close all children of same parent

Tags: d3.js, tree, children

Hey im using this [d3 tree.](http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/2/)

Is there a possibility to close all other child nodes when i click on a node with the same parent. I think it should be something like this but i have no idea to modify it:

```
// Transition exiting ndoes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);
  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

So for example if you look on the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/2/):

- Topic_2 is clicked and its children (Subtopic 4, Subtopic 5, Subtopic 6) are shown
- I click on Topic_1 - children of Topic_1 open
- Children of Topic_2 shall be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzG77/1/) does what you want.  I just made the following change:

```
// Toggle children
function toggle(d) {
    console.log(d);
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  }
  else {
    closeSiblings(d);
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}

function closeSiblings(d) {
    if (!d.parent) return; // root case
    d.parent.children.forEach(function(d1) {
        if (d1 === d || !d1.children) return;
        d1._children = d1.children;
        d1.children = null;
    });
}
```